# How ActiveSupport TimeWithZone retains values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

I tried something like that:

```
a = ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone.new(Time.now,Time.zone)
b = a
a - b  # it gives 0.0 (float)
```

While when I tried:

```
a.to_s  # it gives "2019-06-30 11:11:42 -0700"
a.to_a  # it gives [42, 11, 11, 30, 6, 2019, 0, 181, true, "PDT"]
```

So from where this float number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby's `-` (subtraction) method  from the `Time` class is used for this as you can see looking at the [Rails source code for TimeWithZone](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/b9ca94caea2ca6a6cc09abaffaad67b447134079/activesupport/lib/active_support/time_with_zone.rb#L303).

```
def -(other)
  if other.acts_like?(:time)
    to_time - other.to_time
  elsif duration_of_variable_length?(other)
    method_missing(:-, other)
  else
    result = utc.acts_like?(:date) ? utc.ago(other) : utc - other rescue utc.ago(other)
    result.in_time_zone(time_zone)
  end
end
```

As per the [Ruby docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-2D) it returns a float.

> Difference — Returns a difference in seconds as a Float between time
>   and other_time, or subtracts the given number of seconds in numeric
>   from time.

Comment: So it retains half seconds, milliseconds and etc? how can I check them without subtraction?

Comment: `Time.now.to_i` returns the seconds, `Time.now.to_f` returns the milliseconds